# How can i get this chapter page style?

Tags: fancyhdr, titlesec, algorithms, algorithmic, fncychap

that's my first post here. Can anyone help me to understand how to get this?[image]

Thanks <3

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. What part are you struggling with? Please help us help you and add a minimal working example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Hi @Sbliz and welcome to TeX.SE. You gonna need two separated things. (1) [titlesec + tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271563/customization-of-section-with-tikz-and-titlesec) for your titles and (2) [lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423996/can-one-customize-lstlisting-environment) for your algorithms. Maybe your question will have to be split into two.

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone for your help. I noticed that I asked a question that was too unclear: I wanted to understand what packages were to use to replicate that type of style. But of course you realised the same to me <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to you this minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\makeatletter \renewcommand\thealgorithm{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}} \@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter} \makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Sonny}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Pseudocode}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State $i \gets 10$
\If{$i\geq 5$} 
    \State $i \gets i-1$
\Else
    \If{$i\leq 3$}
        \State $i \gets i+2$
    \EndIf
\EndIf 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible solution with `xcolor`, `titlesec`  and `array`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filleft\huge\bfseries}{\selectfont\color{FireBrick}\scalebox{4}{\thechapter}}{1em}{}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Dataset}

\end{document}
```

[image]